# C++ Populating a vector of objects with user input

Tags: c++, vector

I am new to vectors and new to classes.That being said, I have found some posts about how to create a vector of objects. I want to know how would one go about creating a vector of objects from user input? Say the program asks the user to give the number of employees(class) he/she wants to create. The user wants to add 5 employees. So user must input the employee's last name and first name. I have a for loop in mind but I am not sure how to go about grabbing the user input (Maybe using getline and push_back?) and storing it in the vector.

```
//Lets say class.h looks like this
class Employee
{
private:
    string lastName;
    string firstName;
public:
    void setLastname(string);
    void setFirstname(string);
    string getLastname() const;
    string getFirstname() const;
}
```

Comment: `std::cin` or `std::getline` and `std::vector` should do it.

Comment: The basic skill is to break big problems into subproblems. e.g. design the loop for your program in a way that makes absolutely no reference to *how* you get user input if any, just that you do, and similarly makes no reference to *how* you create an `Employee` object, nor how you store it in a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Employee` class should have a *constructor*. When gathering input, you need all the constructor arguments. Then, to add an `Employee` to a `vector<Employee>`, call `employees.emplace_back( ctor-arguments )`.

Comment: I develop in C# and know only C++98 as procedural language used for ACM contests. Could you explain - is there any difference between using `emplace_back` or instantiating an object and then applying `push_back`? Thank you.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, it avoids unnecessary copying of the object.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev: It even prevents unnecessary _moving_ of an object. (`push_back` will move an object, if allowed to. )

Answer (score 1):

Other users have provided a good examples explaining how to use `emplace_back` in modern C++.
If you work with pre-C++11 versions, there is no `emplace_back` method. In this case, you can collect data in your `vector` manually using old-style `push_back`. You can simply define a vector:

```
vector<Employee> employees;
```

Then, you can read your data line by line, create new objects, fill them according to your business logics and append to your `vector`:

```
int n;

int main() 
{
    cout << "Enter number of employyes: "; cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::string s;
        Employee employee; // Create object

        cout << "Employee " << i << ". First name: "; cin >> s;
        employee.setFirstname(s); // Fill object

        cout << "Employee " << i << ". Last name: "; cin >> s;
        employee.setLastname(s); // Keep filling it

        cout << "Welcome, " << employee.getFirstname() << " " << employee.getLastname() << endl;
        employees.push_back(employee); // Add to vector
    }
}
```

You can also define a constructor taking both `firstname` and `lastname` as arguments to make it easier to work with.

Comment: You mean `Employee employee;` - get rid of the `new Employee()`.

Comment: You'd probably want to `push_back(std::move(employee))`. You don't need the local copy anymore.

Comment: @MSalters Isn't `std::move` a part of C++11? I've tried to provide an example for pre-C++11. How should it be done in previous versions?

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to use the "specify the size ahead of time" pattern; given that we're using `vector`, it doesn't really offer any simplification... or, at least, it wouldn't offer any simplification if you were doing all of the appropriate I/O checks.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev: Fair point. C++98 doesn't have move, it will copy.

Comment: Thanks for giving an alternative to c++11!

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` has a nice method called `emplace_back`, which

> Appends a new element to the end of the container. The element is constructed through std::allocator_traits::construct, which typically uses placement-new to construct the element in-place at the location provided by the container.

So the only thing you are missing to be able to use it is an appropriate constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Employee
{
private:
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
public:
    void setLastname(string);
    void setFirstname(string);
    string getLastname() const{return lastName;}
    string getFirstname() const{return firstName;}

    //create a constructor
    Employee(string firstName, string lastName)
        : firstName(firstName), lastName(lastName)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    vector<Employee> emp;
    int count = 0;
    cout << "Enter the amount of employees to add:" << endl;
    cin >> count;

    string firstName, lastName;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the first and last names" << endl;

        cin >> firstName;
        cin >> lastName;

        emp.emplace_back(firstName, lastName);
    }

    for(const Employee & e : emp)
    {
        cout << "Employee:" << endl;
        cout << e.getFirstname() << " " << e.getLastname() << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you have included the number of elements in the vector beforehand, better to do a .reserve :)

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to use the "specify the size ahead of time" pattern; given that we're using `vector`, it doesn't really offer any simplification... or, at least, it wouldn't offer any simplification if you were doing all of the appropriate I/O checks.

Comment: Thank you! What would be the definition of this constructor?

Comment: @ZhangBing, you don't need anything in the constructor body since it uses a [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Comment: @Hurkyl, the question states that the amount of employees should be entered first. My code only demonstrates the actual process of filling the vector, so I didn't include the IO checks. I believe the OP can do it himself, as well as modify the IO code to fit his actual needs (like additional fields in the class, etc).

Comment: @SingerofTheFall, Thank you! I need to read up on all of this I have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Employee
{
private:
    string lastName;
    string firstName;
public:
    Employee(string paramLastName, string paramFirstName) : lastName(move(paramLastName)), firstName(move(paramFirstName)) {}
    void setLastname(string);
    void setFirstname(string);
    string getLastname() const;
    string getFirstname() const;
}
```

You need a constructor that takes two strings as input. Obviously you could do without this but this reduces verbosity.

> Employee(string paramLastName, string paramFirstName) :
>   lastName(move(paramLastName)), firstName(move(paramFirstName)) {}

You will need to call it in this way.

```
vector<Employee> inp;
string tmp1, tmp2;
while(std::cin>>tmp1 >> tmp2) {
    inp.emplace_back(tmp1, tmp2);
}
```

(This is assuming that you will compile with c++11 support)

Comment: You don't need the `{ }` for `emplace_back`.

Comment: @MSalters thanx. Updated my answer

Comment: Your user input logic is wrong; by the time you check `std::cin`, it's too late.

Comment: @Hurkyl arrgh. The coffee hasn't kicked in yet. Updated.