# Determining If an Array Can be Partitioned into Two Subsequences, Each with Increasing Order

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am currently struggling with a homework problem for my Algorithms Class. A summary of the instruction:

The user enters an integer 'n' to determine the number of test cases.
The user individually enters another integer 'num' to determine the # of elements in each test case.
The user enters the elements of the individual array.

The algorithm has to process the array and determine whether it can be partitioned into two subsequences, each of which is in strictly increasing order. If the result is positive, the program prints "Yes", otherwise it prints "No".

I have 24 hours to complete this assignment but am struggling with the primary problem - I cannot properly process the user input. (come up with an algorithm to split the two subsequences)

update: I got to this solution. It passes 4/5 tests but fails the time constraint in the last test.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

bool run(){
int numbers;
int *arr;
cin >> numbers;
arr = new int[numbers];

for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++)
cin >> arr[i];

long long int MAX = 0;
long long int MAX2 = 0;
string stra = "";
string strb = "";
string result = "";
string total = "";

long long int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++){
if (arr[i] >= MAX && arr[i] != arr[i - 1]){
    stra += to_string(arr[i]);
    MAX = arr[i];
}

else
    if (arr[i] >= MAX2 && MAX2 != MAX){
    strb += to_string(arr[i]);
    MAX2 = arr[i];
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++){
result = to_string(arr[i]);
total += result;
}

long long int len1 = stra.length();
long long int len2 = strb.length();

sum += len1 + len2;

delete[] arr;

if (sum != total.length())
return false;
else
   return true;
 }

int main()
{
int test;
cin >> test;

while (test > 0)
{
if (run())
    cout << "Yes\n";
else
    cout << "No\n";
test--;
}
system("pause");
}
```

Example input:

**2**

5

***3 1 5 2 4***

5

***4 8 1 5 3***

Example output:
Yes
No

Explanation: For the array 3 1 5 2 4, the two strictly increasing subsequences are: 3 5 and 1 2 4.

Comment: `int a[NumOfTestCases][n];` -- You're using variable-length arrays, which don't exist in C++, and neither `NumOfTestCases` nor `n` are initialized yet. Turn up your compiler warnings and use `std::vector`.

Comment: you are using `for(int i...` in nested loops, with the inner hiding the outer. Use different variables - I suggest you use variable `i_test_case` for the outer loop, and `i_element` for the inner one in place of `i`.

Comment: Is a single element part considered "strictly increasing?"

Comment: Would you elaborate? In what sense?

Comment: Would {3,4} and {1} be a valid partition of {3,4,1}?

Comment: Yes, that would be a valid partition.

Comment: Added an explanation of the O(1) space algorithm to my answer.

Comment: Do you think `system("pause")` will help the automatic grading system?

Comment: You are doing a lot of unnecessary work with strings. Why do you think you need to convert numbers to strings?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the existence of any equal or decreasing subsequence of at least three elements means the array cannot be partitioned into two subsequences, each with strictly increasing order, since once we've placed the first element in one part and the second element in the other part, we have no place to place the third.

This seems to indicate that finding the longest decreasing or equal subsequence is a sure solution. Since we only need one of length 3, we can record in O(n) for each element if it has a greater or equal element to the left. Then perform the reverse. If any element has both a greater or equal partner on the left and a smaller or equal partner on the right, the answer is "no."

We can visualise the O(n) time, O(1) space method by plotting along value and position:

```
                          A  choosing list B here
           A              x   would be wrong
           x
value               B        z
^              B    x
|              x
| A          
| x
|    
|    B
|    x
- - - - - - - -> position
```

We notice that as soon as a second list is established (with the first decrease), any element higher than the absolute max so far must be assigned to the list that contains it, and any element lower than it can, in any case, only be placed in the second list if at all.

If we were to assign an element higher than the absolute max so far to the second list (that does not contain it), we could arbitrarily construct a false negative by making the next element lower than both the element we just inserted into the second list and the previous absolute max, but greater than the previous max of the second list (`z` in the diagram). If we had correctly inserted the element higher than the previous absolute max into that first list, we'd still have room to insert the new, arbitrary element into the second list.

(The JavaScript code below technically uses O(n) space in order to show the partition but notice that we only rely on the last element of each part.)

```js
function f(A){
  let partA = [A[0]];
  let partB = [];
  
  for (let i=1; i<A.length; i++){
    if (A[i] > partA[partA.length-1])
      partA.push(A[i]);
    else if (partB.length && A[i] <= partB[partB.length-1])
      return false;
    else
      partB.push(A[i]);
  }
  return [partA, partB];
}

let str = '';
let examples = [
  [30, 10, 50, 25, 26],
  [3, 1, 5, 2, 4],
  [4, 8, 1, 5, 3],
  [3, 1, 1, 2, 4],
  [3, 4, 5, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 1],
  [4, 1, 2, 7, 3]
];

for (e of examples)
  str += JSON.stringify(e) + '\n' + JSON.stringify(f(e)) + '\n\n';

console.log(str);
```

Comment: This observation can be used to prove that the greedy "only switch when you have to" algorithm for partitioning the list always works if it is possible, because it always violates this condition when it fails.  That leads to an O(n) algorithm a lot like @schorsch312 proposes, but also proves that this condition is sufficient.  A simple O(n) algorithm to find these triples using prefix and suffix maximums/minimums, therefore, also works just fine.

Comment: @MattTimmermans what's the "only switch if you have to" algorithm?

Comment: You add to one list until you find an element that is not greater than the previous one. Then you switch lists. If it is also not greater than the previous one in the other list, then you've found a non-increasing triple.  Keep adding to the new list until you're forced to switch again, etc.

Comment: @MattTimmermans wouldn't your algorithm description just above fail for `4 1 2 7 3`? Our lists would be [4] and [1,2,7] then we'd fail on 3 because we should've assigned 7 to [4].

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I failed to consider that the initial list isn't created by a switch.   I still think your condition is sufficient, though.

Comment: @MattTimmermans thanks for the prefix-suffix-as-triple idea ^^

Comment: Proof is Dilworth's theorem, plus appropriate tiebreakers: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem

Comment: Specifically, apply it to the 2D partial order (position, value), where we perturb equal values so that later ones compare less than earlier ones.

Comment: @MattTimmermans added an explanation of the O(1) space algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidEisenstat ! The 2D idea helped me visualise.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Hmm.. yes it can be optimized to O(1) space like yours.

Answer (score 1):

I would go over the entire array once and check two maximal values. If the actual array value is smaller than both maxima, it is not possible, otherwise the proper maximum is increased.

The algorithm does not have to traverse the whole array, if the split condition is violated before.

Here is my code

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool isAddable(const int item, int &max1, int &max2) {
    if (max2 > item) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        if (max1 > item) {
            max2 = item;
        }
        else {
            max1 = item;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

void setStartValue(int &max1, int &max2, const std::vector<int> &vec) {
    max1 = *std::min_element(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + 3);
    max2 = *std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + 3);
}

bool isDiviableIntoTwoIncreasingArrays(const std::vector<int> &vec) {
    if (vec.size() < 3) {
        return true;
    }

    int max1, max2;
    setStartValue(max1, max2, vec);

    for (int i = 2; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        if (max1 > max2) {
            if (!isAddable(vec[i], max1, max2)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (!isAddable(vec[i], max2, max1)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> userVec;
    int tmp1;
    while (std::cin >> tmp1) {
        userVec.emplace_back(tmp1);
    }

    const std::vector<int> v1{3, 1, 5, 2, 4};
    const std::vector<int> v2{4, 8, 1, 5, 3};
    const std::vector<int> v3{3, 4, 1};
    for (const std::vector<int> &vec : {userVec, v1, v2, v3}) {
        if (isDiviableIntoTwoIncreasingArrays(vec)) {
            std::cout << "Yes\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "No\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I set up the user input process with a vector instead of an array?

Comment: @גלעדברקן Good point, I corrected the start parameters. Thanks!

Comment: @Rupert Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33298505/c-populating-a-vector-of-objects-with-user-input

Comment: @Rupert I edited my code to enable user input. As long as you are inputing an integer it will be appended to the user vector. If you enter a non int (e.g. `q`) the user input is finished.

Comment: Can't figure it out with the vector. Read the topic. Still, can't really understand how it would work in this case as we need N separate vectors of integers.

Comment: I think your code returns a false positive for {3,1,1,2,4}

Comment: This answer doesn't support the case where the first three elements all have to belong to the same  subsequence; for example, it gives "No" for { 3, 4, 5, 1, 2 }.

Comment: (That said, this is definitely the right approach. It just has a few bugs that need to be fixed.)

Comment: @ruakh added O(1) space explanation and code to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could resort to using a brute force solution. Notice here I use `vectors`(I think you should as well) to store the data and I use recursion to exhaust out all possible combinations. Keep the problem in mind, solve it and then focus on trivial tasks like parsing the input and matching the way your coursework expects you to enter data. I have added inline comments to make this understandable.

```
bool canPartition(vector<int>& nums) {
     if(nums.empty()) return false;

     vector<int> part1 = {}, part2 = {}; // two partitions

     auto ans = canPart(nums, part1, part2, 0); // pass this to our recursive function
     return ans;
   }

bool canPart(vector<int>& nums, vector<int>& part1, vector<int>& part2, int i)
{
    if(i >= nums.size()) // we are at the end of the array is this a solution?
    {
        if(!part1.empty() && !part2.empty()) // only if the partitions are not empty
        {
            //if you want you could print part1 and part2 here 
            //to see what the partition looks like
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    bool resp1empty = false, resp2empty = false, resp1 = false, resp2 = false;    

    if(part1.empty()) // first partition is empty? lets add something
    {
        part1.push_back(nums[i]);
        resp1empty = canPart(nums, part1, part2, i + 1);
        part1.pop_back(); // well we need to remove this element and try another one
    }

    else if(nums[i] > part1.back()) // first partition is not empty lets check if the sequence is increasing
    {
        part1.push_back(nums[i]);
        resp1 = canPart(nums, part1, part2, i + 1);
        part1.pop_back();
    }

    if(part2.empty()) // is partition two empty? lets add something
    {
      part2.push_back(nums[i]);
      resp2empty = canPart(nums, part1, part2, i + 1);
      part2.pop_back();
    }

    else if(nums[i] > part2.back()) // check if sequence is increasing
    {
      part2.push_back(nums[i]);
      resp2 = canPart(nums, part1, part2, i + 1);
      part2.pop_back();
    }

    //if any of the recursive paths returns a true we have an answer
    return resp1empty || resp2empty || resp1 || resp2;
}
```

You can now try this out with a main function:

```
vector<int> v = {3,1,5,2,4};
cout << canPartition(v);
```

The key take away is make a small test case, add a few more non trivial test cases, solve the problem and then look into parsing inputs for other test cases

Answer (score 0):

- I think this comes down to whether you have an option for a number to appear in the first list or second list or not.
- So, we will keep adding numbers to list 1 and if we can't add any element, we will make it as the start of the new list.
- Let's say, we have both the lists going. If we come across an element to whom we can't add to any of the lists, we return `false`.
- There does arise a situation where we could add an element to **any** of the 2 lists. In this scenario, we adopt a greedy approach as to add to which list.

  - We prepare an array of minimum values from the right. For example, for `[30,10,50,25,26]`, we will have an array of minimums as `[10,25,25,26,(empty here since last)]`.
  - Now, let's trace how we could divide them into 2 lists properly.
  - `30` => **List A.**
  - `10` => **List B.** (since you can't add it first list, so make a new one from here)
  - `50` => **List A.**

    - Here, `50` applies to come after either `30` or `10`. If we choose `10`, then we won't be able to accommodate the next `25` in either of the 2 lists and our program would fail here itself, since our lists would look like `[30]` and `[10,50]`. However, we could continue further if we add `50` to `30` by checking for the minimum stored for it in our minimums array, which is `25`.
  - `25` => **List B.**
  - `26` => **List B.**
  - So, our final lists are `[30,50]` and `[10,25,26]`.
- Time complexity: **O(n)**, Space complexity: **O(n)** and you can print the 2 lists as well.
- If we come across a sorted array which is strictly increasing, we return true for them anyway.

Comment: I think we can have O(1) space. Please see my answer.